# If $f$ is odd how does this imply that $f$ is symmetric about the origin in polar coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is an exercise from a precalculus book I am reading : [image]

But isnt $f(x) = x$ a counterexample to this statement? When you plot this in polar coordinates it is a spiral which is not symmetric about the origin. What am I missing ?

Edit: The curve on the bottom picture is $r = \theta$ and the line is defined by an arbitrary point on the spiral and the origin. The curve is not symmetric about the origin.(or otherwise the circle would intersect the curve on the opposite side of the line)

[image]

Comment: Symmetric about the origin is not the same as symmetric about the y-axis, I think this may be the cause for your confusion.

Comment: You are not plotting the identity function in polar coordinates properly. It will not be $r=\theta$ but $\cos\theta=\sin\theta$.

Comment: But I am not supposed to plot the identity function. I am supposed to plot $r = \theta$

Comment: $r=\theta$ is not the graph of the function $f(x)=x$ which is the identity function.

Comment: I know they are not the same. But look at what the exercise is. It says that if we have a function $f(x) = x$ for example I should plot $r = f(\theta) = \theta$

Comment: That does not imply symmetry about the origin in polar coordinates (or atleast I dont know that it does) I will post a picture to illustrate my idea of why $f(x) = x$ is a counterexample

Comment: Yeah I know. I deleted my comment. What you want is $(-R,\theta)$ or $(R,\theta+\pi)$

Comment: I think the question is wrong. As per the criteria here(pg 2), the curve is going to be symmetrical about the y-axis: http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/GRAPHING-IN-POLAR-COORDINATES.pdf

Comment: I thought so too. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If we are supposed to interpret the equation $$r(\theta)=f(\theta)\qquad(-\theta_0<\theta<\theta_0)$$ as polar representation of a curve $\gamma$ then $\gamma$ has the representation
$$\gamma:\quad\theta\mapsto{\bf z}(\theta)=\bigl(f(\theta)\cos\theta,f(\theta)\sin\theta\bigr)$$
in cartesian coordinates. If $f$ is odd then
$${\bf z}(-\theta)=\bigl(f(-\theta)\cos(-\theta),f(-\theta)\sin(-\theta)\bigr)=\bigl(-f(\theta)\cos\theta,f(\theta)\sin\theta\bigr)=R_y\bigl({\bf z}(\theta)\bigr),$$
where $R_y$ denotes reflection on the $y$-axis. This show that the curve $\gamma$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.

Comment: We are not supposed to interpret it as a polar representation of the curve. What this exercise tells us is that the relation between the radius and the angle in polar coordinates is the same as that of the vertical and horizontal axis in rectangular coordinates.